# Incomplete factory update makes btrfs filesystem unusable?

Tags: opensuse, btrfs

After an incomplete update from the factory repo my opensuse 12.1 btrfs filesystem is unusable. I have plenty of disk space free but zero inodes. When I try to delete or create a file it gives me the error no space available? How can I fix this?

Here is how I solved it: http://www.nrtm.de/index.php/2012/03/13/the-joys-of-btrfs-and-opensuse-or-no-space-left-on-device/

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btrfs doesn't have a limitation in the number of inodes. It's not your problem.

Boot a livecd and mount the partition. The btrfs driver fix the most of the problems when mount a volume.

Comment: I got it fixed. It's a OpenSUSE problem with snapper and to many snapshots. Snapper is bad configured.